# install package not working in docker build

Tags: r, installation, docker-build

I am creating a docker image build of my code, to deploy the code

I am trying to install the package sprkline

I am getting this logs after install.packages(sparkline)

```
#15 0.714 Installing package into '/home/dsp/workspace/code/R/user_library/ubuntu/4.1'
#15 0.714 (as 'lib' is unspecified)
#15 3.016 trying URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/sparkline_2.0.tar.gz'
#15 3.499 Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 204329 bytes (199 KB)
#15 3.612 ==================================================
#15 3.851 downloaded 199 KB
#15 3.851 
#15 4.156 * installing *source* package 'sparkline' ...
#15 4.160 ** package 'sparkline' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
#15 4.160 ** using staged installation
#15 4.175 ** R
#15 4.178 ** inst
#15 4.184 ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
#15 4.580 ** help
#15 4.602 *** installing help indices
#15 4.626 ** building package indices
#15 4.858 ** installing vignettes
#15 4.864 ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
#15 5.258 ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
#15 5.621 ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
#15 5.622 * DONE (sparkline)
```

After this I check if the installed folder is present at the location using

`list.files("home/dsp/workspace/code/R/user_library/ubuntu/4.1")`

which gives the result `character(0)`, which looks incorrect. Further it gives error when
I try to load using `library('sparkline`)`

I observed that while running the code in console, if I install and do list.files, I am able to see the folder for sparkline
Can you please let me know what is incorrect with the docker build

Comment: You’re gonna have to show your Dockerfile — actually, a minimal version: a [mcve]

Comment: I further debugged the issue. The error is that the .R file where I try to load libarary('sparkline')  has .libpaths() as empty and they keep on showing empty even after .libPaths(new = "home/dsp/workspace/code/R/user_library/ubuntu/4.1").